# Непонятное поведение потоков в android приложении

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, ui

Есть два метода. Основной - initializeGame() :

```
public void initializeGame()
    {
        new Thread(new onePoint()).start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Видно, что он запускает новый поток, описанный в классе onePoint :

```
class onePoint implements Runnable {
        (...)
        public void run() {

            (...)

            while (...) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                (...)

                if (...) {
                    setOpacityOnButton(...);
                }
            }
        }
```

Так вот. Метод initializeGame запускается по нажатию на кнопку старта. Дополнительный поток создается, механическая работа с переменными в этом дополнительном потоке идёт нормально. Однако графическое представление не меняется (Я вызываю это изменение обращением к методу setOpacityOnButton() ) до того момента пока основной поток не закончится (т.е. примерно 6 секунд проходит). Почему так происходит? Точно не из-за if (проверял). Вот на всякий случай этот самый метод setOpacityOnButton() :

```
void setOpacityOnButton(int id, final int opacity) {
        final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(id);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (opacity != 0) {
                    btn.setText(Integer.toString(opacity));
                }
                else {
                    btn.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Покажите, как вы вызываете `initializeGame()`? Мне кажется, вы вызываете `Thread.sleep()` прямо в UI-потоке, а потом пытаетесь в нем же менять текст на кнопке.

Comment: initializeGame() вызывается по  нажатии на кнопку старта (самый обычный элемент view).

Comment: Графическое представление у Вас не меняется, поскольку вы трэд на 6 секунд насильно усыпили

Comment: Так я усыпил не тот поток, в котором это представление меняется.

Comment: @DeathCookies, если initializeGame вызывается из onClick, то Вы тормозите UI thread, поэтому все что выполняется в runOnUiThread ждет эти 6 секунд.

Comment: @ravikwow поставил initializeGame() в onCreate(). В таком случает приложение как бы виснет на эти 6 секунд а потом всё идет нормально. В общем, аналогичная ситуация

Comment: А чего вы вообще добиваетесь этой задержкой? Уберите ее совсем, это наверняка решит проблему с установкой текста на кнопку.

Comment: @zRrr эта задержка - необходимая часть программы

Comment: Необходимая для чего? Заставка? Блокирование интерфейса пользователя? Выполнение какого-то действия через 6 секунд после инициализации?

Comment: @zRrr разъяснять не хочу. В общем, так должно быть

Comment: @DeathCookies, onCreate это тоже UI thread. Вы что-то делаете не так, скорее всего нарушена логика приложения. Без подробностей, которые Вы не хотите предоставить, Вам не смогут помочь, т.к. информации мало. Может поможет http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/thread.php

Comment: @ravikwow если вы мне поможете, могу предоставить проект со всеми исходными кодами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась, господа. Было неправильно вызывать метод Thread.sleep() в основном потоке, так как именно через него происходит изменение ui, т.е. графического представления программы.

Comment: т.е. нужно положить конструкцию с методом Thread.sleep()  в новый поток

Comment: именно об этом все Вам и писали.